# How can I smoothly slide a flexbox side panel offscreen?

Tags: css-transitions, angular-material, css-transforms

I have a fairly simple flex layout built on Angular Material. It has a side panel that can be slid offscreen. I'm currently using negative margins to handle that so that the main content box follows its movement with a width adjustment, which [works well](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/d4L0umqs/). However, this results in animation that's not smooth. Apparently it's more of a chore for the graphics rendering mechanism than translation.

How can I accomplish the same using `translateX`? Here's my demo layout:

```
<div ng-app="sandbox" layout="row" class="wrapper" ng-class="{'sidebar-out': sidebarOut}">
    <div flex="60" class="main md-padding">
        <h1>Main Content</h1>
        <button class="toggler" ng-click="sidebarOut=!sidebarOut">Toggle sidebar</button>
    </div>

    <div flex="40" class="sidebar md-padding">
        <h2>Sidebar</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

The sidebar movement is handled with simple Angular directives and CSS:

```
.sidebar-out .sidebar {
    transform: translateX(40vw)
}
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/o7e8kL0p/)**

The problem is that the main content box doesn't adjust size as the sidebar translates off screen. How can I make that happen? Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help in anyway? - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/camden_kid/9uf95w9r/35/)

I think there may be a better way to do this bit though...

```
.sidebar-out .main {
    transform: scaleX(1.7)
}
```

Markup

```
<div ng-app="sandbox" layout="row" class="wrapper" ng-class="{'sidebar-out': sidebarOut}">
    <div id="newMain" flex="60">
      <div id="mainContent">
        <h1>Main Content</h1>
        <button class="toggler" ng-click="sidebarOut=!sidebarOut">Toggle sidebar</button>
      </div>
      <div class="main md-padding">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div flex="40" class="sidebar md-padding">
        <h2>Sidebar</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    background: pink;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#newMain {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
#mainContent {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.sidebar,
.main {
    height: 100vh;
}
.main {
    background: #fff;
    transition: all .5s;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.sidebar-out .main {
    transform: scaleX(1.7)
}

.sidebar {
    background: #ddd;
    transition: all .5s;
}
.sidebar-out .sidebar {
    transform: translateX(40vw)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Are you offering one solution here, or two? The fiddle demo has scrollbars on both axes. Are you able to remedy that?

Comment: @isherwood Before I look into that I wonder if Sidenav isn't a better solution - https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/sidenav. I think it's a nice way of achieving you aims. Your current solution seems to mix flex and transitions which isn't ideal.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the sidebar to cover the main content area of the page. We change our layout to not use the sidebar for mobile/portrait.

Comment: @isherwood See the updated Fiddle (and answer) for no scrollbars. I'm only offering one solution at the moment :-) I just wonder if there isn't a better CSS way than using the magic number **1.7** for scaleX.

Comment: It doesn't seem like content is flexing. I'm not sure why I don't see pink, but have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/f95a4a24/

Comment: @isherwood I'm unable to achieve your requirements with the solution in my answer and I don't think it's the right way to go. Bit busy today but I'll have a think about it as it's an interesting problem.